# HTML/ JavaScript radio button selections to output as summary of options

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a form that saves all of your selections of radio buttons and outputs as a summary upon submission. I am fairly new to JavaScript so please bear with me.

You are supposed to select between, let's say, three options per section. Depending on what was previously selected after you press Submit, it will open a lightbox and give you a summary of your choices before you submit the choices to be sent via email.

For what I have right now, there is only one section and three options to choose from.

HTML:

```
<div id="options">
  <form method="get">  
    <label class ="rad">
      <input type="radio" name ="O1" value="small"/>
      <img src="img.jpg">
    </label>

    <label class ="rad">
      <input type="radio" name ="O2" value="small"/>
      <img src="img.jpg">
    </label>

    <label class ="rad">
      <input type="radio" name ="O3" value="small"/>
      <img src="img.jpg">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#radio_submit").click(function (e) {
var checked_O1_radio = $('input:radio[name=O1]:checked').val();
var checked_O2_radio = $('input:radio[name=O2]:checked').val();
var checked_O3_radio = $('input:radio[name=O3]:checked').val();
if(checked_O1_radio===undefined || checked_O2_radio===undefined || checked_O3_radio===undefined)
    {
        alert('Please select a leather option then continue.');
    }else{
        alert('You Chose "' +checked_O1_radio);
    }else{
        alert('You Chose "' +checked_O2_radio);
    }else{
        alert('You Chose "' +checked_O3_radio);
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if i under stand your question correctly:

you can use same name then automatically only one will be selected and find the selected leather with a single check.

```
<label class ="rad">
  <input type="radio" name ="O1" value="small"/>
</label>

<label class ="rad">
  <input type="radio" name ="O1" value="medium"/>
</label>

<label class ="rad">
  <input type="radio" name ="O1" value="large"/>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id = "Submitbutton"/>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Submitbutton").click(function (){
    console.log($('input:radio[name=O1]:checked').val());
  })
});
```

Please mark it as to answer if it helps you.

Comment: You can use a radiogroup which will provide information about which one is selected. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radiogroup

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think it is working. However I am having trouble getting the data to be shown in a summary right now, just to see that it's making the right selection. Would using the POST function in HTML be the proper way to do it?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, there was just an error in my code.